# How to automatically adjust span with its outer div

Tags: html, css

I have an outer div 'draggable', If we write a very big content, it automatically gets expanded, but the span width remains fixed.

HTML

```
<div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content" style="word-break: keep-all">
   <span class="too" >
      <div id="symbol" style="POSITION: relative;float:right;">
         <span class='switch-icons'>-</span>
         <a id="switch"><img id="img1" src="images/minus.png" alt="minus" height="15" width="15" ></a>
         <a  onclick="javascript:closeFullScreenView()"><img  src="images/close-bt.png" alt="close" height="15" width="15" ></a>
      </div>
      <p class="ui-widget-header" style="FLOAT: left">
         FileNo.:
         <s:property value="fileNo"/>
      </p>
   </span>
   <div id="ajaxContent" style="overflow-Y:auto;">
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.too {
    width: auto;
    display: block;
    float: right;
}
```

The span having class 'too' is not expanding accordingly. I have tried float as well, but its not working.

Comment: Can you post a fiddle please? so we can help you.

Comment: can you create a fiddle with full code for better understanding? @Coder

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it is working fine for me. It may be some other styles in your code causing this issue. Could you please post a fiddle , so that we can check more on this.